# How to populate unbounded datagridview comboboxcell with values from db?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I am using Winforms and I have a DataGridView which has 2 bomboboxcell and 3 textboxcell and datagridview isn't connected to any datasource.

Comboboxcell 1 has 2 values "Supplier/Customer" which I have set using the Datagridview collection. The comboboxcell 2 is populated based on the values selected from the cell 1 CODE 1.1 represents this behaviour.

**CODE 1.1**

```
    //bind custom event to Account Type combo
    private void accTypeEditingControl(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvAccOpBal.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            ComboBox accType = e.Control as ComboBox;

            if (accType != null)
            {
                accType.SelectionChangeCommitted -= new EventHandler(accTypeSelectedIndexChanged);

                accType.SelectionChangeCommitted += new EventHandler(accTypeSelectedIndexChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    //custom selected index changed event
    void accTypeSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (((ComboBox)sender).SelectedIndex > -1)
        //{
            String accTypeValue = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString();

            if (accTypeValue == "Customer")
            {
                loadCustomerList();

            }
            else if (accTypeValue == "Supplier")
            {
                loadSupplierList();

            }
        //}
    }

    //load customer combobox
    public void loadCustomerList()
    {
        dtCustomer = accountOpeningBalanceQueryClass.getCustomerList();

        if (dtCustomer.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell) dgvAccOpBal.CurrentRow.Cells["Selector"];

            cell.DataSource = null; //null the datasource
            cell.Items.Clear(); //clear the items
            cell.DataSource = dtCustomer; //set new datasource
            cell.DisplayMember = dtCustomer.Columns["CustomerName"].ColumnName; //set the member
            cell.ValueMember = dtCustomer.Columns["ID"].ColumnName; //set the member values
        }
    }
```

The user add the new row by clicking a button and fills the corresponding row and saves the record. All works fine till here as expected.

My question is: When the user search a specific record a dataset is retured as show in CODE 1.2. How do I get the comboBox cell to display the VALUE he selected originally instead of just a blank box. I know the code of getting the value from the DB and put in a value. The ideal would be if I could put that variable in the display of the comboBox. Keep in mind that the comboBoxcell 2 needs to be poulated with the supplier/customer list and the comboboxcell 2 displaying the value selected before.

**CODE 1.2**

```
        ![Problematic Screen][1]
        //get for input data
        voucherNoSearch = txtBxVoucherNoSearch.Text.Trim();

        //validate form input
        if (voucherNoSearch != "")
        {
            //get purchases info from db
            dsAccountOpeningInfo = accountOpeningBalanceQueryClass.getAccountOpeningBalanceInfo(ref voucherNoSearch);

            if (dsAccountOpeningInfo.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 && dsAccountOpeningInfo.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0) //account opening table, account opening details table
            {
                //load textbox
                txtBxVoucherNo.Text = dsAccountOpeningInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["VoucherNo"].ToString();
                txtBxDebitTotalAmount.Text = dsAccountOpeningInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DebitTotal"].ToString();
                txtBxCreditTotalAmount.Text = dsAccountOpeningInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CreditTotal"].ToString();

                //clear datagridview rows
                dgvAccOpBal.Rows.Clear();

                //load datagridview
                for (int i = 0; i < dsAccountOpeningInfo.Tables[1].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    dgvAccOpBal.Rows.Add();

                    if (dsAccountOpeningInfo.Tables[1].Rows[i]["FKSupplierID"].ToString() == "NULL") //customer row
                    {
                        DataGridViewComboBoxCell accTypeCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvAccOpBal.Rows[i].Cells[0];
                        accTypeCell.Value = "Customer";

                        loadCustomerList();

                        DataGridViewComboBoxCell selectorCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvAccOpBal.Rows[i].Cells[0];
                        selectorCell.Value = dsAccountOpeningInfo.Tables[1].Rows[i]["FKCustomerID"].ToString();
                    }
                    else if (dsAccountOpeningInfo.Tables[1].Rows[i]["FKCustomerID"].ToString() == "NULL") //supplier row
                    {
                        DataGridViewComboBoxCell accTypeCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvAccOpBal.Rows[i].Cells[0];
                        accTypeCell.Value = "Supplier";

                        loadSupplierList();

                        DataGridViewComboBoxCell selectorCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvAccOpBal.Rows[i].Cells[0];
                        selectorCell.Value = dsAccountOpeningInfo.Tables[1].Rows[i]["FKSupplierID"].ToString();         
                    }
                }

                //calculateTotal();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No record found against this Voucher No!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                //refresh form
                resetFormInput();
            }
        }
```

As seen in the screen I cant see any previous values selected nor my comboboxcell 2 contains any customer/supplier list. When I select value from comboboxcell 1 only then the comboxcell 2 populates with values and the values are shown when that cell is clicked 3 times. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The link is attached here: http://imageshack.com/a/img811/1395/powh.png

Comment: Isn't there anyone who can help me with this?